# Why does NHibernate's LINQ provider generate invalid T-SQL for a GroupBy()?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to do what seems like a simple query for the number of `Products` produced by each `Manufacturer`, but NHibernate isn't generating T-SQL that MS SQL Server finds valid.

```cs
session.Query<Product>()
    .GroupBy(p => p.Manufacturer)
    .Select(grp => new {Mftr = grp.Key.Name, ProductCount = grp.Count()})
    .ToList();
```

This seems dead simple, but the SQL statement that NHibernate generates **doesn't include all the necessary column names**, so it fails when running against a SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server CE database. If I point the same code to an in-memory SQLite database, it works fine.

More information is below, and I also created a [small console application that demonstrates my problem](http://control-v.net/stackoverflow/7124495/NHibernateGroupBy.zip). **How do I fix this problem?**

---

#### Generated SQL

```sql
select manufactur1_.Id,
    cast(count(*) as INT), 
    manufactur1_.Id, 
    manufactur1_.Name 
from "Product" product0_ 
    left outer join "Manufacturer" manufactur1_ 
    on product0_.Manufacturer_id=manufactur1_.Id 
group by manufactur1_.Id   -- Where's manufactur1_.Name?
```

#### Entities

```cs
public class Product {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
public class Manufacturer {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

#### FNH Mappings

```cs
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product> {
    public ProductMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("1");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.Manufacturer).Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class ManufacturerMap : ClassMap<Manufacturer> {
    public ManufacturerMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id) .GeneratedBy.HiLo("1");
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because the Linq Provider isn't very good...do you want an answer in QueryOver?

Comment: @dotjoe: So I'm beginning to learn. I've never used QueryOver/ICriteria before, so an answer using that method would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I'd stay away from the NHLinq provider in critical code. It's fine for pet projects but it's not up to the level of Linq to SQL or even Linq to Entities yet. Too bad, because NH is the best in almost every other respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a QueryOver version...

```
//alias variables
Manufacturer m = null;
ManufacturerProducts dto = null;

var result = Session.QueryOver<Product>
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Manufacturer, () => m)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .SelectGroup(() => m.Id).WithAlias(() => dto.Id)
        .SelectGroup(() => m.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Name)
        .SelectCount(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => dto.ProductCount))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ManufacturerProducts>())
    .List<ManufacturerProducts>();
```